# Unable to cast object of type System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, gridview

I wrote a method that deletes rows from my an asp.net Gridview when the delete button is clicked and another method for when the edit button is clicked.
Both Edit and Delete buttons are part of the built in gridview controls.

However when I press these buttons (edit/delete)and exception is thrown.
**Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'.** which is pointing at the line

```
Button btn = (Button)sender;
```

The problem here is that this line is not related to either of the edit or delete methods. It is related to the asp button in another column, and for that reason I am lost. How can I resolve this issue? What is causing both the OnRowDeleting and OnRowEditing conflict with the showResponses method?

Here is the aspx

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvShowQuestionnaires" HeaderStyle-CssClass="table_header" CssClass="view" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#f3f4f8" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames='QuestionnaireID' OnRowDeleting="gvShowQuestionnaires_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvShowQuestionnaires_RowEdit" FooterStyle-CssClass="view_table_footer" OnRowCommand="showResponses"> 
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionnaireID" HeaderText="ID" HeaderStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-CssClass="bo"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="QuestionnaireName" HeaderText="Questionnaire Name" />           
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Results" HeaderStyle-Width="150px">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("QuestionnaireID") %>' OnClick="showResponses" text="Results"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Options" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="true" EditText="Edit"></asp:CommandField>
    </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is the code behind:

```
protected void gvShowQuestionnaires_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    int questionnaireID = (int)gvShowQuestionnaires.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex)].Value;
    GetData.DeleteQuestionnaire(questionnaireID);
    gvShowQuestionnaires.DataSource = DT;
    gvShowQuestionnaires.DataBind();
}

protected void gvShowQuestionnaires_RowEdit(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
   string id = gvShowQuestionnaires.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[0].Text;
   Session["qID"] = id;
   Response.Redirect("~/members/edit_questionnaire.aspx");
}

protected void showResponses(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    string id = btn.CommandArgument.ToString();
    Session["qID"] = id;
    Response.Redirect("~/members/questionnaire_responses.aspx");            
}
```

Any help would much appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems reasonably clear to me. Here:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ... OnRowCommand="showResponses">
```

you bind the [`RowCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) event to `showResponses`. And here, in `showResponses`, you assume that the sender is a button:

```
protected void showResponses(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    string id = btn.CommandArgument.ToString();
    Session["qID"] = id;
    Response.Redirect("~/members/questionnaire_responses.aspx");            
}
```

The sender *isn't* a button - it's the grid view. If you want the command argument, you should use [`GridViewCommandEventArgs.CommandArgument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventargs.aspx).

```
protected void showResponses(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Session["qID"] = e.CommandArgument;
    Response.Redirect("~/members/questionnaire_responses.aspx");            
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting an error `No overload for 'showResponses' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'` on the line `<asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("QuestionnaireID") %>' OnClick="showResponses" text="Results"/>` How can I solve this?

Comment: @Rupert: Use a different handler for that event, basically. You may well want to make both handlers call into the same single method after extracting the `CommandArgument` appropriately.

Comment: @JonSkeet Which event handler should be used? It appears that the onRowCommand is conflicting with the OnRowDeleting handler. How would I extract the relevant `CommandArgument`? I have limited experience with the Gridview control so I would not know which event handler to use.

Comment: @Rupert: I don't know the details of when which event is used - but you already know how to get the command argument from a button click - because you had that code before. You just can't use the same code for both the button click *and* the RowCommand event.

Comment: Finally figured it out. Thanks =]

Answer (score 0):

Add a CommandName attribute to your button1 in the GridView.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="button1" CommandName="Button1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("QuestionnaireID") %>' OnClick="showResponses" text="Results"/>
```

Then in showResponses do this...

```
protected void showResponses(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Button1") {
         Session["qID"] = e.CommandArgument;
         Response.Redirect("~/members/questionnaire_responses.aspx");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var btnSender = (Button)e.CommandSource;
```